# What happened with NVIZ?

Tags: qgis, nviz

I'm unable to find and run NVIZ and now I've read several places that it's not functioning in the latest versions of QGIS? Is this a temporarily bug or definite?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include links to any of the several places that you have read that, please?

Comment: Thought I needed to install it via plugins, and read that others had issues as well. If this post can be deleted.