# QGIS 2.4 NVIZ Solution

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, nviz

I am going to ask this question better:

[What happened with NVIZ?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114406/what-happened-with-nviz)

I do not know the exact version that nviz stopped working but it seems around version 2 of QGIS. There are two ways to get to nviz in QGIS 2.4

1) Processing toolbox - I double click on the nviz which is under visualization which is under GRASS commands and receive this error:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 181, in executeAlgorithm
message = alg.checkBeforeOpeningParametersDialog()
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 511, in checkBeforeOpeningParametersDialog
msg = Grass7Utils.checkGrass7IsInstalled()
 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 361, in checkGrass7IsInstalled
cmdpath = os.path.join(path, 'bin', 'r.out.gdal.exe')
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, 8fdd08a

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/Bobby Pescatore/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Bobby Pescatore/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\Bobby Pescatore\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\MetaSearch\\ext-libs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:/Users/Bobby Pescatore/Desktop/Batimetria']
```

2) From GRASS Tools - In the module list you can type nviz and if you try to initiate it from there you get this error:

[image]

Any help on this issue would be great. I get that the whole thing is open source so there is no dedicated support but I can't imagine that nobody has solved this yet.

For anybody who needs this functionality immediately, I have learned from the research I have done that if you work directly from GRASS and not through GIS this should work. I haven't tried yet but plan to tomorrow. Will update then.

Comment: Maybe you need to open a bug report with QGIS...